# Rotating Labels in IB?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, interface-builder

Does anyone know how to Rotate Labels (or any object) in Interface Builder??

Zach

Comment: Rotate as in "45 degrees" or as in "switch between a set of possible contents"?

Comment: 90 degrees, so they're vertical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rotate UI objects in IB, you have to do it in code.